# MS Access: Quickly Create a Test Table with 1000000 Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to create and insert table quickly in MS-Access 2003 like below (with the help of SQL Query statement only):

**Table Name: MyTestTable**

```
==========
MyColName
----------
       1
       2
       3
       4
       5
       6
       .
       .
       .
 1000000    
========
```

one such example is there for MS-SQL Server at the page:
http://sqlservice.se/sv/start/blogg/sql-server-performance--death-by-correlated-subqueries.aspx

```
;WITH cteNums AS
( 
    -- I use this common table expression to create a list of numbers from 1 to 1 000 000 
    SELECT top 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o1.object_ID) AS n 
    FROM master.sys.columns o1 
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns o2 
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns o3 
) 
INSERT INTO table1 (col2) --insert into table1 
OUTPUT INSERTED.col2 INTO table2 (col2) --use the output clause to insert into table2 
SELECT DATEADD(d,n,GETDATE()) -- create dates from the list of numbers 
FROM cteNums;
```

**I want to create such a TEMPORARY table in MS-Access**

Comment: Is it homework ? Why this constraint ?

Comment: Is this an access database or a linked SQL server table?

Comment: I want to check performance (endTime - startTime) of MS-Access and may be useful in the next project.

Comment: @adaam Pure MS-Access, DataBase version Access2000, AccessVersion Access2003

Comment: AFAIK this cannot be done in SQL without an existing table. VBA is easy enough.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai SQL is a generic term, the version required is ACE/Jet.

Comment: Use VBA to create the table and run a `Do While Loop` until `recordcount = 1001`, inserting a record each loop.